# eloquent javascript chapter 5 array reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I've been trying to figure out how count gets defined as 0 within the reduce method then is used within the function. Is there anyone who could describe how this code works step by step? Thanks!

```
let ranges = [[125184, 125259], [125264, 125274], [125278, 125280]];

    console.log(

      ranges.reduce((count, [from, to]) => {
          return count + (to - from);
        }, 0)

  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly initializing it with the last argument to reduce.  Change that zero to something else and you'll see the output changes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

```js
let ranges = [[125184, 125259], [125264, 125274], [125278, 125280]];

    console.log(

      ranges.reduce((count, [from, to]) => {    // count gets 0 initially
      console.log('count->', count, 'from->', from, 'to->', to)
          return count + (to - from);
        }, 0)              // passing initial value to count

  );
```

So, initially `count` gets 0 as default value you have passed. After that initial call count will contain whatever the function returns (see the log inside the `.reduce()`).

The array on which you are calling `reduce()` is an `array` containing `array` of length two. So, second parameter is a array of length two (`[from, to]`) because `.reduce()` is going to iterate over it one by one and get those inner arrays. Now, those arrays will be [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) using `array destructuring assgnment` and will be collected in `from` and `to` variable.

So on first iteration you are adding difference of the inner array `(to - from)` to 0 and returning it. For the second iteration, whatever you have returned from first (75) will be the value of `count` variable and so on..

You can read more about `.reduce()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Thank you. I have one final thing I'm unclear about. The second parameter [from, to] --> Would you be able to explain in detail how from actually gets its initial value of 125184 and how to gets 125259? For some reason I'm having a mental hiccup on how reduce is pulling those values from an array within an array.

Comment: @StevenTidd In the second parameter `array destructuring` is being used (updated my answer). `reduce()` is iterating over your _ranges_ array and returning the inner array of length 2 (one by one). Now, [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is being used to assign _first element_ of the array to `from` variable and _second element_ to the `to`  variable. Eg: `var [a, b] = [10, 20]` now, a will have 10 & b will have 20. Please see the links I've mentioned in my ans(updated) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation is that, the count from `(count, [from, to])`, is an accumulated value, and we defining the initial value as second parameter of `reduce` method

```
let initialValue = 0;//Or whatever value
console.log(

  ranges.reduce((count, [from, to]) => {
      return count + (to - from);
    }, initialValue);
```

);